# Kentico13 - How to add content teasers in richtext field?

Tags: kentico

We are using Kentico XP 13.0.44. Our content editors create news articles with rich text fields in built-in CKEditor v4.14.

Our editors ask for a feature to insert content teasers into rich-text. My idea was to create a custom CKEditor plugin and utilize Kentico's "Insert Link" dialog (editor.config.LinkDialogURL).

[image]

This works, but ideally I would like to hide all tabs except "Content". I tried to add query parameters like `&anchor_hide=1&email_hide=1&libraries_hide=1&web_hide=1` to the "/CMSFormControls/Selectors/InsertImageOrMedia" LinkDialogURL but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to somehow customize this dialog or create custom dialogs for CKEditor? Am I on the wrong track and is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a "Content Teaser"?

Comment: Sorry, sure. With "content teaser" I mean HTML markup that is basically a link to a Kentico page asset, enriched by asset properties (e.g. title and featured image of that target page). Our content editors want to refer to related assets of a news article at any position in a rich-text field and more "appealing" than a simple link.